# Specify AppleScript bundle icon

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to assign an icon to my AppleScript bundle, but without success.

Steps:

- Added the icon (applet.icns) to the bundle's `/Contents/Resources` directory
- Modified the bundle's  `/Contents/Info.plist`:

  ```
  <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
  <string>applet.icns</string>
  ```

** edit **

I ran the 'Set Bundle Icon File' script in the [Applet Bundle Tools](http://macosxautomation.com/applescript/bundletools/index.html).  It did not change the situation.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: This may not work for an AppleScript bundle.

First I open the icon in preview.app.

I select the full picture and type Command-C

The way I typically change icons for files is that I select the file and type Command-I

In the info window that opens, I then select the current icon in the upper left.

Type Command-V and the icon (theoretically) will change to the picture in the clipboard

Comment: Wow, that work!  Thanks so much.  Question, where does it store that icon?  If I distribute the bundle, will the icon be lost?

Comment: I have tried sharing it before, but I don't know where the icon is stored (sorrry), but I have had about 50/50 success rate with it being shared and keeping the icon.  You will have to try it yourself, and see if it works.  Just try copying it with a flash-drive to another computer and see if it keeps the icon.